# SinonJS stub for an async function with one argument and multiple callback values

Tags: node.js, sinon

I have an async function call like this:

```
db.findUser(username, function (err, user) {

});
```

I have tried to create the stub like this:

```
dbMock.findUser = sinon.stub().callsArg(1, "mockUsername", {"err":null, "user":mockFindUserResponse});
```

Also I tried with callsArgWith:

```
        dbMock.findUser = sinon.stub().callsArgWith(1, "mockUsername", null, mockFindUserResponse);
```

But no luck.

Sinon seems to ignore the second callback value.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to use callsArgOnWith:

```
        dbMock.findUser = sinon.stub().callsArgOnWith(1, {username: "mockUsername"}, null, mockFindUserResponse);
```